# Changing the colour of points when using plot

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I have got some points on a chart that I have plotted using qplot from ggplot2. The only thing is that they are automatically set to various shades of blue and I am having trouble changing them to the colour that I want.

I am simply plotting them using

```
qplot(ID, TIME, sample, colour = TYPE)
```

I thought this should give me multicoloured points according to the tutorial I have been following however they are nearly indistinguishable shades of blue. I have been doing some research and have found `colour = I("red")` for example, but how do I include that in my statement when I am setting the colour by type. I tried adding it in after the `colour = TYPE` part but it still isn't working. I am sure I am missing something simple here but it would be great if  I could get a pointer from someone,

Many thanks,

Comment: Try `qplot(ID, TIME, sample, colour = factor(TYPE))`

Comment: Thats excellent @Roland. Thanks. Do you know how I might be able to have even more autonomy in my colour choice?

Comment: See `scale_colour_manual`(http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_manual.html): `p + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue", "green"))`

Comment: If you want more fine control over the plot, don't use `qplot` (which is, after all, more simple on purpose) but use `ggplot`. Although you can specify scales for `qplot` just like for `ggplot` it's easier to understand the concept (the "grammar of graphics") if you use the latter.